Probability of a palindrome of n-digits
One number is generated at random. What is the probability of getting a palindrome?
For even numbers, the favorable cases are $$10 ^{n/2 }$$ and the probability is $$\frac{1}{10^{n/2}}$$
This is the given answer. So the first digit can be $0$.
I think that for odd numbers the favorable cases are $$10^{(n-1)/2} * 10 = 10^{(n+1)/2}$$
The probability is then $$\frac{1}{10^{(n+1)/2}}$$
But the given answer is $$\frac{1}{10^{(n-1)/2}}$$
Not sure what is the right answer.

For an odd # of digits, the middle digit is unconstrained.

Are you allowed to start your number with a $0$?

@HackR That is what I was wondering too. If the solution for the even numbers is $\frac{1}{10^{n/2}}$, so I think the number can start with a $0$.

@HackR it doesn't matter. Whatever the first $n/2$ digits are, as long as the last $n/2$ digits are independent they will match with probability $10^{-n/2}$.

Be specific.  Do you mean that an $n$-digit natural number is chosen at random, or that a natural number with at most $n$ digits is chosen at random, or that a string of $n$ digits is chosen at random?  Is $1000$ a palindrome if $n=4$?  What about if $n=7$?  All these lead to different answers.

If you just mean a string of $n$ digits, then clearly the answer is $10^{-\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}$, since $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ is the number of digits at the end that must match digits at the start.

In an odd-length palindrome, the middle digit can be anything, so you can remove it and get an equivalent even-length palindrome of length $n-1$.
Since an even-length palindrome of length $n$ has probability $$\frac{1}{10^{n/2}},$$ the odd-length has probability $$\frac{1}{10^{(n-1)/2}}.$$
These can be combined using the floor function $$\frac{1}{10^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}}$$

If you have an odd number of length n=5, one instance of a palindrome would be $12021$. As the middle number can be any number you could have $12121, 12221, 12321, 12421, 12521, 12621, 12721, 12821, 12921$. That's why I think one needs to multiply $10^{(n-1)/2}$ by $10$.

What formula are you using to calculate the probability given the number of favourable cases? It looks like perhaps 1/number? This is incorrect, it's favourable cases / total cases

For even: $$\frac{10^{n/2}}{10^n} = 10^{n/2-n} = 10^{-n/2} = \frac{1}{10^{n/2}}$$ For odd: $$\frac{10^{(n+1)/2}}{10^n} = 10^{(n+1)/2-n} = 10^{(1-n)/2} = \frac{1}{10^{(n-1)/2}}$$

In "For odd", in the numerator of the first fraction, how do you get the $10^{(n+1)/2}$?

@J.Evans You calculated it yourself. It is the number of favourable cases.
